# SwiftUI - how to respond to TextField onCommit in an other View?

Tags: swiftui, textfield

I made a `SearchBarView` view to use in various other views (for clarity, I removed all the layout modifiers, such as color and padding):

```
struct SearchBarView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    @State private var isEditing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Search…", text: $text, onCommit: didPressReturn)
                 .overlay(
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        
                        if isEditing {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.text = ""
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "multiply.circle.fill")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
    }
    
    func didPressReturn() {
        print("did press return")
    }
}
```

It looks and works great to filter data in a `List`.

But now I'd like to use the `SearchBarView` to search an external database.

```
struct SearchDatabaseView: View {
    @Binding var isPresented: Bool
    @State var searchText: String = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                SearchBarView(text: $searchText)
                // need something here to respond to onCommit and initiate a network call.

            }
            .navigationBarTitle("Search...")
            .navigationBarItems(trailing:
                Button(action: { self.isPresented = false })  {
                    Text("Done")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

For this, I only want to start the network access when the user hits return. So I added the `onCommit` part to `SearchBarView`, and the `didPressReturn()` function is indeed only called when tapping return. So far, so good.

What I don't understand is how `SearchDatabaseView` that contains the `SearchBarView` can respond to `onCommit` and initiate the database searh - how do I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is possible approach

```
struct SearchBarView: View {
    @Binding var text: String
    var onCommit: () -> () = {}   // inject callback

    @State private var isEditing = false
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            TextField("Search…", text: $text, onCommit: didPressReturn)
                 .overlay(
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: "magnifyingglass")
                            .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                        
                        if isEditing {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.text = ""
                            }) {
                                Image(systemName: "multiply.circle.fill")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
    }
    
    func didPressReturn() {
        print("did press return")
       // do internal things...

       self.onCommit()      // << external callback
    }
}
```

so now in `SearchDatabaseView` you can

```
VStack {
    SearchBarView(text: $searchText) {
      // do needed things here ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this affect other views that use `SearchBarView` but don't need the `onCommit` requirement, eg `List` filtering? (I'm away from my Mac and cannot test it myself until later today).

Comment: No, as it is seen - `let onCommit: () -> () = {}` - has default empty closure

Comment: What do I put where you wrote `// do needed things here ...` ? I'm getting an `Extra trailing closure passed in call` error when I add the curly brackets after `SearchBarView(text: $searchText)`.

Comment: That had to be variable `var onCommit: () -> () = {}`. Updated with fix.

Comment: Brilliant! Please note didPressReturn call from onCommit: parameter should end with parenthesis to prevent the error "Expression resolves to an unused function"